# Find cardinal number of a list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, unique, singly-linked-list, function-definition

How can i find only the elements that appears once in the list and return the cardinal number?For example if my list consist of {3,2,1,1,2,4} i expect for return the counter to be 4 and not 6 cause we do not count the duplicate numbers.
Here is the code that i have written so far.

```
struct Node 
{ 
    int data;  
    struct Node *next; 
}; 
  
int Find_cardinal(struct Node *start) 
{ 
    struct Node *ptr1, *ptr2
    ptr1 = start; 
    int counter=0;
    /* Pick elements one by one */
    while (ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next != NULL) 
    { 
        ptr2 = ptr1; 
  
        /* Compare the picked element with rest 
           of the elements */
        while (ptr2->next != NULL) 
        { 
            /* If duplicate */
            if (ptr1->data == ptr2->next->data) 
            { 
                break;
            } 
            else 
                //do what?
                ptr2 = ptr2->next; 
                
        } 
        ptr1 = ptr1->next; 
    } 
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing that can be filled in the place marked “//do what?” that will make the function work without changes in other code. This is because the code in that places falls into “If `ptr1->data` is duplicated, then…”, but what you need is to count the things that are **not** duplicated, so you need some place in the code that says “If `ptr1->data` is **not** duplicated, then count it.” Think about how you can do that.

Comment: Additionally, avoid writing code like `int counter;` that does not initialize the object it defines. Initialize objects unless there is good reason not to. Use `int counter = 0;`. You cannot count anything if you do not start with zero (or some other known starting point).

Answer (score 2):

Your function implementation is wrong.

Even the condition in the first while loop

```
while (ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next != NULL)
```

is incorrect because if the list contains only one node the loop will not be executed and the function will return 0.

And within the function the variable `counter` is not being changed.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function `Find_cardinal` that is better to name like `count_distinct` can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
}; 
typedef struct Node Node_t;

size_t assign( Node_t **head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        Node_t *tmp = *head;
        head = &( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
    
    size_t i = 0;
    
    for ( ; i < n && ( *head = malloc( sizeof( Node_t ) ) ) != NULL; i++ )
    {
        ( *head )->data = a[i];
        ( *head )->next = NULL;
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }
    
    return i;
}

size_t count_distinct( const Node_t *head )
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    for ( const Node_t *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        const Node_t *prev = head;
        
        while ( prev != current && prev->data != current->data )
        {
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        
        if ( prev == current ) ++n;
    }
    
    return n;
}

FILE * display( const Node_t *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node_t *head = NULL;
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4 };
    
    assign( &head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    printf( "There are %zu distinct data in the list.\n", count_distinct( head ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
There are 4 distinct data in the list.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using your current construct. The idea is to iterate through the list and 'remember' or check whether a particular item is duplicate, so somehow you need to store the unique values that have been passed. Below is one naive implementation. 
Sample output:

```
Input values
3
2
1
1
2
4

Unique count: 4
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void printAll(struct Node *start){
    struct Node *ptr1;
    ptr1 = start;
    while (ptr1 != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", ptr1->data);
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
    }
}

int countUnique(struct Node *start) {
    struct Node *uniqueNodes; //this will hold the unique value
    struct Node *ptrInput;
    ptrInput = start;
    int counter = 0;
    /* Pick elements one by one */
    while (ptrInput != NULL) {
        //Loop through the list which hold the unique value
        struct Node *ptrUnique;
        ptrUnique = uniqueNodes;
        int isFound = 0;

        while (ptrUnique != NULL && !isFound) {
            if (ptrInput->data == ptrUnique->data) {
                isFound = 1; //value is found in the unique list
            } //end if
            ptrUnique = ptrUnique->next;
        } //end while

        if (! isFound) { //when not found, then need to add the value in the unique list and increment the counter afterwards
            struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
            newNode->data = ptrInput->data;
            newNode->next = NULL;

            //If uniqueNodes is still empty, then just change the pointer of the uniqueNodes to the newly created item.
            //Otherwise, just put the newly created item on the head of the list
            if (uniqueNodes == NULL) {
                uniqueNodes = newNode;
            } else {
                newNode->next = uniqueNodes;
                uniqueNodes = newNode;
            } //end else

            counter++;
        } //end if

        ptrInput = ptrInput->next;
    } //end while
    return counter;
}

int main(void) {
    struct Node *node1 = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *node2 = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *node3 = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *node4 = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *node5 = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *node6 = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));

    node1->data = 3;
    node2->data = 2;
    node3->data = 1;
    node4->data = 1;
    node5->data = 2;
    node6->data = 4;

    node1->next = node2;
    node2->next = node3;
    node3->next = node4;
    node4->next = node5;
    node5->next = node6;
    node6->next = NULL;

    printf("Input values\n", NULL);
    printAll(node1);
    int uniq = countUnique(node1);
    printf("\nUnique count: %d\n", uniq);
    return 0;
}
```